# Pod Google MLKit in Kotlin Multiplatform - cinterop-GoogleMLKit.klib does not exist

Tags: ios, kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform

When I try to use Google ML Kit pod, i get an error.

KMP config:

```
cocoapods {
        summary = "Summary"
        homepage = "Page"
        version = "1.0.0"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        framework {
            baseName = "library"
            extraSpecAttributes["resources"] = "['src/commonMain/resources/**']"
        }
        pod("GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition"){
            version = "3.2.0"
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
:library:iosMain: cinterop file: /Users/user/library-sdk/library/build/classes/kotlin/iosArm64/main/cinterop/library-cinterop-GoogleMLKit.klib does not exist
```

I tried to change library, removed targets and now is:

```
 //iosX64()
 iosArm64()
 //iosSimulatorArm64()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
pod("GoogleMLKit/TextRecognition") {
    moduleName = "MLKitTextRecognition"
    version = "3.2.0"
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).